# Does Exo Slam count as a melee attack in Outbreak alternative ending

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

The Reckoning DLC added a new ending for Game over, man! Easter egg on Outbreak (or was it here since Havoc came out?)

So in the new ending, you do everything normally until the step when you upgrade your keycard. You have to use melee attacks to kill them so they drop special cards. But since Exo Slam is also a melee attack, can I use it to complete the step?

The fact that Exo Slam gives you 50 points makes me think that I can't.

Answer (score 1):

I think it does count I was running solo yesterday and I didnt melee a single zombie other than slammed them as crawlers are easier to kill, suddenly I had 5 cards, I thought I messed up so I shot them and collected the cards and it turned grey so I did it right the first time but the only thingbi can think of is that I exo slammed a group of zombies